# How to open terminal then run a program on the terminal simultaneously on startup?

Tags: boot, lxterminal

My Pi already logs in automatically (goes to Desktop on startup). I wanted my python program to run automatically when pi boots but I need to use the USB numeric keypad input in my program (that is why I need to run the program through the terminal) and with no monitor connected..

So how do I run terminal on startup, then run my python program `sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/final/project.py`automatically on the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify which OS you are using. I am assuming you are using Raspbian OS.

To open terminal automatically on start up, edit ***/home/user/.xinitrc*** and add the following line

**exec gnome-terminal &**

To run any program on starting terminal,(again, you need to specify which shell you are using. I am assuming 'bash' shell. you can know your shell by typing "echo $SHELL" in your terminal)

**Bash and Its Start up File Execution Algorithm**

Execution order

```
When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.

After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The first 2 files do not exist in my setup, so it runs ~/.profile.

When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the file ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.

This may be inhibited by using the --norc option. The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

        Files run ...      If ...
        1st: /etc/profile  Interactive login shell
        2nd: ~/.profile
        3rd: ~/.bashrc     Interactive non-login shell
```

Source for Bash start up execution order : http://savage.net.au/Linux/html/bash.files.html

Comment: Your question is already answered in separate posts in this forum. I have answered assuming you are new to Raspberry PI/Linux. Please search patiently before posting a question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Wheezy. I'm going to try your answer when I get home, will update you later. 

Sorry about that, I have searched prior to asking but they did not work for me (the rc.local and lxde, or maybe I did them wrong) so I decided to ask to allow me follow up questions.. 

BTW, I saw an answer: `gnome-terminal -e "python /path/filename.py"` and I tried it in the terminal, another terminal popped up and my project.py ran. That's what I wanted to happen but I just do not know where to put it to run on boot.. any ideas?

Comment: Try adding that line to "/etc/rc.local" and make sure you give root privileges

Comment: can you tell me what to do and type at the 2nd part (bash part)? I'm still new to linux and programming alike.

Comment: create a file named '.bash_profile' in your home folder and add 'python /path/filename.py' as you mentioned above. Just manually open the terminal and verify your program automatically starts or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Raspberry Pi where you run your program in a terminal

- Create a "desktop" file (called "`runthis.desktop`", for example) in `/home/pi/.config/autostart`
- Copy these lines to the new file ("`runthis.desktop`"):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Comment=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
Hidden=false

Name=RootCam

Exec=x-terminal-emulator --working-directory=/home/pi/projects/RootCam -e /home/pi/projects/RootCam/main &
```

Change "Name" and "Exec" as desired and reboot the Pi. Tell your parents you love them.