# Autostart Python script doesn't work

Tags: python, boot

I am trying to get my Raspberry Pi to open a terminal and run a Python script when it boots up. I have followed the instructions of some guides and have so far been unsuccessful.

My steps

I have made a Python file called testfile.py located in /home/pi/Documents/testfile.py

The contents are as follows:

```
print('hello')
input('press any key to exit')
```

I have added a file called testfile.desktop to /home/pi/.config/autostart/testfile.desktop.

The contents are as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=testfile
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Terminal=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Exec=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/testfile.py
```

When I double click this file, the terminal opens and the Python script runs as expected, but when I reboot the Raspberry Pi the script doesn't run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I duplicated what you did using an up-to-date Raspbian Buster in a Pi 4 B.  (I wish all questions were as clear and complete as yours!)

Double-clicking the file on my machine brought up the `thonny` IDE.  (*Note:*  The 'any' key doesn't work because `input()` needs an `enter` to complete.) On reboot, I observed the same result you did.  However, installing `xterm` and changing the `Exec` line to

`Exec=xterm -hold -e '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Documents/testfile.py'`

causes an xterm window to open and the Python program to run.  I was following [these debugging instructions](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-run-a-raspberry-pi-program-on-startup/method-2-autostart).

So, there is some interaction I don't understand between autostart, Python, and terminal.  Perhaps you could try a Python program that leaves some evidence in the file system, such as writing a tiny output file.

**Edit:** See [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109561/85029) which appears to be more useful than mine.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I was following the same guide you linked, but didn't catch the xterm installation part (should have added that to the original question).

Comment: If you discover why it doesn't work without `xterm`, please let everyone know.

Comment: Found an alterative way using x-terminal-emulator instead of xterm. (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27581/how-to-open-terminal-then-run-a-program-on-the-terminal-simultaneously-on-startu). still not sure why normal exec doesn't work and i can't find a way of getting to the logs of the startup.

Answer (score 2):

Create a file:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/startupbrowser.service
```

Put all lines below there:

```
[Unit]
Description=testfile service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/testfile.py
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
Restart=on-failure

User=root
Group=root
SyslogIdentifier=testfile

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save the file and reload the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Test that is your code is running:

```
sudo service testfile start
```

Check the log by:

```
journalctl -f -u testfile.service
```

It will give you the real-time log of your python code to troubleshoot what's going on.

If everything was good as you intended, run this command to enable is as a startup service:

```
sudo systemctl enable testfile.service
```

Comment: This will run the python script as a sevice, which is interesting, but will it show the terminal and the outputs of the script?

Comment: @Achmed Yes, easily. The answer has updated, check it again.

Comment: ([*"```lang-none"* for the second block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you. I have changed the second part but I think that was not distinguished.